# I have to show $p(x-\lambda)$ is an irreducible monic poynomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that $\mathbb{F}$ is a field , $|\mathbb{F}|\geq n \geq 2$. I know $p\in \mathbb{F}[x]$ is an irreducible polynomial and let $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$ , I have to show $p(x-\lambda)$ is an irreducible monic poynomial.

Answer (score 1):

Assume p(x) to be of degree n then p(x)=x^n+ax^(m-1)+... and so 
p(x-c)=(x-c)^m+a(x-c)^(m-1)+...=a monic polynomial. Just expand. Now if 
p(x-c)=f(x)g(x) then p(x)=p((x+c)-c)=f(x+c)g(x+x) and so p is reducible. p(y)=f(y+c)g(y+c)

Answer (score 0):

For $p(x-\lambda)$ to be monic, you need $p(x)$ to be monic, which you forgot to mention.

Hint: if $p(x-\lambda) = g(x-\lambda) h(x-\lambda)$, what do you suppose $p(x)$ is?

Comment: right $p$ is irreducible monic polynomial. in text say  noting about $p(x)$ , $p(x)$ is general.